# leetcode practice: can find the bug of returning a negative number from sum method

Tags: linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to solve [445. Add Two Numbers II](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers-ii/) from LeetCode where it is asked:

> Given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers, add the two numbers and return it as a linked list. The most significant digit comes first and each of their nodes contain a single digit.

For some test cases, I am getting negative number from the sum method that I have implemented. I think it is impossible to get any negative digit in my code. Can you help me finding the bug?

Below is the code that I tried:

```
 /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */

class Solution {
    public ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
        //ListNode previous = null;
        int len1 = 0;
        int len2 = 0;
        ListNode head1 = l1;
        ListNode head2 = l2;

        while(l1!=null){
            len1++;
            l1=l1.next;
        }
        while(l2!=null){
            len2++;
            l2=l2.next;
        }

        int sum=0;
        if (len1 >= len2){
            sum= sum(head1,head2,len1,len2);
            
        }else{
            sum= sum(head2,head1,len2,len1);
        }
        
        String sumString = "" + sum;
        ListNode extraHead = new ListNode(1);
        ListNode copy = extraHead;
        for(int i = 0;i<sumString.length();i++){
            ListNode bit = new ListNode(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sumString.charAt(i))));//Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(sumString.charAt(i)))
            extraHead.next = bit;
            extraHead = extraHead.next;
        }
        return copy.next;
        
    }
    
    public int sum(ListNode l1, ListNode l2, int len1, int len2){
        
            int diff = 0;
            int resLen = 0;
        
            diff = len1 - len2;
            resLen = len1;
        
            int[] res = new int[resLen];
            ListNode fast = l1;
            ListNode slow = l2;
            for(int count = 0; count<diff; count++){
                
                res[count] = fast.val;
                fast = fast.next;
                
            }
            for(int count = diff;count < res.length;count++){
                res[count] = fast.val + slow.val;
                fast=fast.next;
                slow=slow.next;
            }
            int sum = 0;
            for(int i = len1;i>0;i-- ){
                sum = sum + res[len1-i] * (int)Math.pow(10,i-1);
            }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Here is the error message that I get:

```
Error Details 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "-"
  at line 68, java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString
  at line 648, java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt
  at line 776, java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt
  at line 41, Solution.addTwoNumbers
  at line 54, __DriverSolution__.__helper__
  at line 87, __Driver__.main
```

Here is the input causing the error:

```
[3,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9]
[7]
```

Comment: 1st of all, do not post pictures for people to read text. 2ndly, just push both lists into stacks, then pop and sum, easier than dealing with pointers.

Comment: @BingWang Stack will cost memory and sometimes it might not be possible to allow extra memory.

Comment: The problem causing because your `sum` function returning an int where an integer-overflow occur. Check my [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28462292) where I attach the sample input for which the error occur.

Comment: Try to figure out a way so that you can return a string from your `sum()` method.

Comment: @biqarboy Thank you so much for pointing the actual issue-Integer Overflow and editting my queston.